# How does swift handle multiple cookies in header response navigationAction.request.allHTTPHeaderFields?["Set-Cookie"]

Tags: ios, swift, cookies

How does swift handle navigationAction.request.allHTTPHeaderFields?["Set-Cookie"]. I have a response with multiple cookies, and I want to know how to deal with it, since navigationAction.request.allHTTPHeaderFields?["Set-Cookie"] returns a string. I cannot test this at all because I am trying to implement Single sign on, and I have to wait until it is deployed to see if it works.

Answer (score 1):

A better solution for future users just in case is to implement WKNavigationDelegate and iterate through the cookies like so:

```
func webView(_: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor: WKNavigationResponse, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationResponsePolicy) -> Void) {

    let response = (decidePolicyFor.response as! HTTPURLResponse)
    let cookies = HTTPCookie.cookies(withResponseHeaderFields: response.allHeaderFields as! [String : String], for: response.url!)

    for cookie in cookies {
       //cookie.value, cookie.name etc... do logic here
    }


    decisionHandler(.allow)
 }
```